# how can I send a complete XML node to a function as text?

Tags: vb.net

I have the following function call which I extract the full node to XML:

```
mvarXmlSalida = Util.Salida("0", "", xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//file/"))
```

This is the function that obtains the elements:

```
Public Function Salida(ByVal est As String, ByVal err As String, Optional node As XmlNode = Nothing) As String

    Dim m_xmld = New XmlDocument
    Try
        m_xmld.LoadXml("<tx><estado></estado><info></info></tx>")
        m_xmld.SelectSingleNode("tx/estado").InnerText = est
        m_xmld.SelectSingleNode("tx/info").InnerText = err

        If Not node Is Nothing Then
            m_xmld.SelectSingleNode("//").AppendChild(node)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        m_xmld.InnerText = "Error al cargar nodos de error"


    End Try
    Return m_xmld.InnerXml

End Function
```

When I run the function, it returns the following error:

> The expression must be evaluated as a set of nodes.

I know that it sends several nodes when I call it from there, the function can receive only one node or several nodes.

example of the node to be obtained

```
<Transport>
 <file>
    <name>test.txt</name>
    <size>1,52 Kb</size>
    <type>.txt</type>
    <data>test data</data>
    <option>ExactName</option>
  </file>
<Transport>
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of the xml?

Comment: here I uploaded the xml example